# Google Spreadsheet script "toggle" hide/view column/row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know that using these function I can show and hide columns:

```
function showColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showColumns(2,3);   // B-D, three columns starting from 2nd 
  sheet.showColumn(7);      //  G, column number 7
}

function hideColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideColumns(2,3);  // B-D, three columns starting from 2nd
  sheet.hideColumn(7);     // G, column 7
}
```

But for that, I need two buttons or menu script, one for hiding and one for showing the columns.

I would like to know if there is a "toggle" function that exist so I can activate the hide/show function without needing 2 buttons or menu items.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a way to detect the hidden/unhidden state of a column with a script, but the toggle behavior can be implemented by storing the state in [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service). Here is the function that manages the properties and calls either of two other functions, as appropriate.

```
function toggleColumns() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden')) {
    showColumns();
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false); 
  }
  else {
    hideColumns();
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because all properties are stored as string, i.e. false is stored as "false", which is true!  So we'd better use string comparison.